# can someone correct this dfa java

Tags: java

my output if the user for example types something that doesn't belong to my program needs to be 1 "rejected" only but many "rejected" keeps appearing on the output please help thanks

import java.util.Scanner;
public class thecomp {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("input 0 and 1");
    String a = input.next();

    if (a.equals("01")){
        System.out.println("L1 = {w|w starts with 0 and ends with 1}");
    } 


    if (a.equals("00")) {
        System.out.println("L1 = {w|w starts with 00}");
    } 


    if (a.equals("0")) {
        System.out.println("L1 = {w|w starts with 0}");
    } 



    if (a.equals("0011")) {
        System.out.println("L1 = {w|w ends with 11}");
    } 



    if (a.equals("0011")) {
        System.out.println("L1 = {w|w consists of two 0's and two 1's}");
    } 

      else  {
        System.out.println("REJECTED");



    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: i tried giving all the if statements the corresponding else statements that says rejected but when i enter for example the letter "s" 5 rejected keeps appearing

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Please clarify it?

Comment: Use `else if` instead of `if` in order to chain `if` statements when you only want one of them to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it consistently outputting "rejected" infinitely? Also, use a switch statement:

```
switch(a) {
    case "00":
        System.out.println("It's equal to 00");
        break;
    case "01:
        System.out.println("It's equal to 01");
        break;
    // Continue
}
```